# Qual é a diferença entre os protocolos FTP, FTPS e SFTP?

Tags: ftp, sftp

Qual é a diferença entre os protocolos FTP, FTPS e SFTP e em quais contextos devo utilizar cada um?

Comment: Eu ia responder, mas acho que é fora de escopo. Vamos ver o que o resto da comunidade pensa.

Comment: FTP e FTPS são "iguais", a diferença que o último utiliza trafego criptografado (sob SSL). Já a diferença entre FTPS e SFTP é a maior. Ambos nestes casos são criptografados, a diferença é que o FTPS exige duas conexões já o SFTP apenas uma, um outro detalhe é que o FTPS usa certificados X.509 (uma vez que usa SSL) e o SFTP, como o nome sugere usa SSH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

de forma resumida:

**FTP**: é o Protocolo de Transferência de Arquivos sem nenhum tipo de criptografia, ou seja é um modo pouco seguro.

**SFTP**: Protocolo de Transferência de Arquivos por SSH, ou seja criptografado, esse é um modo mais seguro em relação ao **FTP**.

**FTPS**: O FTPS é um FTP com uma camada SSL para a segurança. "Protocolo Seguro de Transferência de Arquivos"

tendo em vista as diferenças dos 3, use o que for mais adequado para o seu arquivo, se for um arquivo sensível que não deveria ser interceptado, use o **SFTP** agora se além da criptografia, você quer ter certeza que esta se comunicando com o servidor real, use o  **FTPS** pelo fato de ter SSL.
Se não for nenhum dos dois casos acima, o **ftp** normal já será o suficiente para você.